# Cant get attributes new value when using live()

Tags: jquery

In the code below, I update the data-mode value using jquery. That value comes from the server.

So now if it's 'Block', when I click it, if all goes well at the server, it'll be 'Unblock'.

It updates to 'Unblock'. I can see this using dev tools in Mozilla. But when I click it again, I still get the old value. Not the new one.

What wrong am I doing here, and how do I do this right?

```
<span class="mod-user" data-mode="Block" data-handle="3">Block</span>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('.mod-user').live('click', function() {

    var mode        = $(this).data("mode");
    var userHandle  = $(this).data("handle");
    var handle  = 'mode='+mode+'&handle='+userHandle;

    if(handle){

            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                 url: "/modset/",
                data: handle,
            dataType: "json",
               cache: false,

                beforeSend: function(html) {

                    $('.mod-user[data-handle="'+userHandle+'"]').empty();
                    $('.mod-user[data-handle="'+userHandle+'"]').html('Wait..');

                    },
               success: function(preData){

                    if (preData["success"] == false){

                        delete preData["success"];


                    }else if (preData["success"] == true)
                    {

                        delete preData["success"];

                        $(this).html('');

                        alert(preData['response']);

                        $('.mod-user[data-handle="'+userHandle+'"]').html(preData['response']);
                        $('.mod-user[data-handle="'+userHandle+'"]').attr('data-mode',preData['response']);


                    }else{
                        alert('Error');
                    }



              },
            });
            }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: why are you using .attr()? use .data() through out.

Comment: Wow! I cant believe. That worked!

Comment: i'll post it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on this line:

```
$('.mod-user[data-handle="'+userHandle+'"]').attr('data-mode',preData['response']);
```

you're using .attr(). You should be using .data() throughout.